# Can we split the values with delimiter and insert into table

Tags: sql

I want to split the sting with multiple values and insert the same into table.
For eg: i/p - '1,2,ABC|3,4,XYZ'
I need to split the with delimiters and insert the multiple records into a table.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please tag with database you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Basically, I want to split the string and insert it into an existing table with 4 columns.
in DB2.

Ex: String - '001, 1, 2, ABC' , this string should be split and inserted into a table that has 4 columns.